# URL aliases: rewrite, routing, not sure

Tags: asp.net

ASP.net 4.0 / IIS7.

I want to "alias" a single web form to appear as various extensionless urls. Given a form in my web root called "**mySite.com/ColorWebForm456.aspx**":

1. I want it served as multiple names, e.g., mySite.com/Color,  mySite.com/Colour,  mySite.com/Colors, mySite.com/Coler, etc., without creating folders and duplicate forms with those names.
2. I never want mySite.com/ColorWebForm456.aspx displayed in the browser, it needs to display as mySite.com/Color, even if the user somehow acquires it and types in that exact ~.aspx address.
3. The variations will account for several alternate or mis-spellings users might attempt - I don't want them "corrected", however.  So, if a user types in mySite.com/Colour, the url is NOT rewritten to mySite.com/Color, but the same page is served via ColorWebForm456.aspx as the requested "mySite.com/Colour".

I've seen so many articles on this that I'm not even sure where this would be best handled: in Global.asax, IIS7 URL Rewrite, web.config, etc., and I'm not even sure this is *technically a case of url rewriting or routing*... ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with ASP.NET 4 routing for web forms, or if you are using MVC its available too: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Except potentially for #3; it would work, but you would have to explicitly declare the variations you want.  In that case, rewriting supports regular expression matching, so that might be better for what you are looking for.

I had issues setting up URL rewriting and various aspects of web forms, so be aware.  There is some setup required for a rewrite module potentially (I could have done it wrong too), where URL routing is already built in and handled.

HTH.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that article and tried it. Works locally for me (VS2010), but fails when uploaded to our IIS 7.5 cloud service, yielding a 404.0 error, specifically because it expects a directory named ~/Color to exist, and it does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rewrite engine available:

(using ISAPI Rewrite .htaccess syntax)

```
# redirect any requests for the filename back to the friendly URL
RewriteRule ^/colorWebForm4567.aspx(.*) /Color$1 [NC,R=302]

# rewrite /Color requests to the web form
RewriteRule ^/(Color|Colour)/(.*) /ColorWebForm4567.aspx$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Following article expalins it all, but if you will be using a web host after you complete your application I would check with the hosting provider first to see if they are offering everything you need to have:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As a side note: Search engines dislike it, if you publish content under different URLs ("[duplicate content](http://www.google.com/search?q=seo+duplicate+content)").

So my recommendation would be to stick with one (rewritten) URL, not multiple (rewritten) URLs for the same content.